# How to if check data in real-time-db FIREBASE

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I would like to check/compare if a value is inside this data:

[image: 1]

example:

```
const uid = '35nv594aotgcv'

#check if uid is inside

firebase
 .database()
   .ref('followers/2mvouwB0E0aEN5MnAhOLWaHiu6b2')
     .once("value", snapshot => {
         if (snapshot.exists()) {
            const data = snapshot.val(); // data are the other two uid's in the image above
         }
     });
```

So how can I check if the `const uid = '35nv594aotgcv'` is inside the snapshot data?

or if I have an Array with uid's like `const uids = ['234', '343', '3242', ...]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you're looking for [`DataSnapshot.hasChild()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.DataSnapshot#haschild). With that you can check whether the snapshot has a certain child node.

Something like:

```
firebase
 .database()
 .ref('followers/2mvouwB0E0aEN5MnAhOLWaHiu6b2')
 .once("value", snapshot => {
   if (snapshot.hasChild('35nv594aotgcv')) {
     console.log('Yes');
   }
 });
```